# Importing matrix with different row length

Tags: matlab, matrix, import, large-data

I have large data files and I would like to import 12 columns of data for further use. However the row length will be different in each instance. I would import the selected columns only but below the data I need are some blank rows followed by extra numbers which aren't necessary, so I'm wondering how to import just the data I need? I don't mind specifying and end row but this would be different for each case and I'm not sure if I'm missing anything else obvious! To help I've attached a print-screen of an example of the data I'm working with:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wthijvufac2jmrc/Capture.JPG?dl=0]

To summarise I only require the "blue" data above the purple boxes, each file I will use will have the same layout except there may be more/less rows of data.

Comment: have you tried `[xlsread('filename.xls','C9697:N9705') ; xlsread('filename.xls','C9716:N9720')] `

Comment: Hi, @Nishant thanks for getting back to me! I think I've done that using the import tool, but this wont apply to every file which has different numbers of "useful" rows. I think what I would like is to have a way for it to automatically stop importing any values after the row beginning with Joints if that makes sense?

Comment: as the file is large, i would suggest you fall back to reading the file row by row and concatenating the required rows.

Comment: @Nishant I can do that anyway using the import tool and specifying an end row I thought? As I'll have a large number of data files I was hoping to find an endpoint automatically maybe using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
I have updated the code to give you a better understanding of the process:

```
% An empty array:
importedarray = [];
% Open the data file to read from it:
fid = fopen( 'dummydata.txt', 'r' );
% Check that fid is not -1 (error openning the file).
% read each line of the data in a cell array:
cac = textscan( fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n' );
% size(cac{1},1) must equals the # of rows in your data file.
totalRows = size(cac{1},1);
fprintf('Imported %d rows of data!\n',totalRows)
% Close the file as we don't need it anymore:
fclose( fid );

% for total rows in data
for k=1:totalRows
    fprintf('Parsing data on row %d of %d...\n',k,totalRows);
    currentRow = cac{1}{k,1};
    fprintf('Row contains:\n%s\n',currentRow);
    % finish (break from loop) when encounter an empty row:
    if isempty(currentRow)
        fprintf('Empty row encountered (#%d). Exiting the loop...\n',k);
        break;
    end

    eachRowElement = strsplit(currentRow, ' ');
    fprintf('Splitting row to %d elements...\n',length(eachRowElement));
    fprintf('Converting row to floats...');
    eachRowElement2num = cellfun(@str2num,eachRowElement,'UniformOutput',false);
    fprintf('Done!\n');

    fprintf('Converting cell to matrix...');
    importedarray(k,:) = cell2mat(eachRowElement2num);
    fprintf('Done!\n');
end
clearvars cac k fid totalRows currentRow eachRowElement eachRowElement2num;
```

Given your example image (that all the columns of each row are filled with floats and on an empty row you stop) this should do the job giving info along the way. If not you will be able to tell what is the issue by looking the line the code stopped. I include code to eliminate the unnecessary variables after importing. This must be done manually or you can create a function to perform the task (functions' work space is different the the temporary variables are deleted on function return, see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html). Hope this helps.

PS. In your example you keep 12 columns skipping the first two. The above code will import the whole row. You can choose what columns to keep later by using matrix indexing, like:

importedarray = importedarray(:,3:14);

if these columns don't change you can incorporate this into your function.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for writing this @stefanos. This is no way a reflection of you but when I try your code it says that the "index exceeds matrix dimensions". And I am new to Matlab so I'm confident I'm doing something wrong. Also I'm not sure if this is clear in my OP but I don't need any of the numbers from the purple cells downwards. Lastly, things like totalColumns and cac is coming up in the workspace so maybe I need apostrophes around things? So sorry for my lack of knowledge here!

Comment: @CPG1711 I have updated the code. Please take your time to step through it and let me know if it works and if not were it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Thank you again! I think we're getting closer as theres no error but I cant see the data for a reason I'm sure I'm missing, when I run it with the file i need it comes up with:
"Imported 11666 rows of data!
Parsing data on row 1 of 11666...
Row contains:

Empty row encountered (#1). Exiting the loop..."
then in the workspace it has ans that has a value of 0 and importedarray that has a value of []

If it helps the top of the sheets I'll be using will look like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/mix4lgnq0ssxbc0/Capture2.JPG?dl=0 
and the data I'll need will always begin from C6

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. From your output I understand that it stops in the first line because its empty (even not the case in your screenshot). You can bypass that - better yet now that everything starts in row 6 by adjusting where the main loop starts:

"for k=6:totalRows <-- ignore previous rows."

Comment: Hi Stefanos, I'm even more sorry for my delayed response, in the time I found a way to tell matlab to import the first "block" only using the headers, but thankyou for all of your help I would have not learnt as much as I did without it!